# sqlite table is empty after relaunching the android app

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

in my app I access my sqlite db in two ways. one from a service which fetches the data from the server and updates the database. and two there are other methods that read the data and show it to the user. what happens is that that when I update the database, when I close the app and open it again, the data is gone and tables are empty?!?! I open the db when I launch the app and close (if I do) in onDestroy().

```
public boolean updateTopic( final String oldTopicID, final Topic newTopic )
{
    if( newTopic == null )
        return false;

    boolean result = false;

    result = super.write( new DatabaseWriteRequest<Boolean>()
    {

        @Override
        public Boolean requestImplementation( SQLiteDatabase database )
        {

            int result = database.update( TABLE_NAME, getContentValues( newTopic ), COLUMN_ID + " = ?", new String[] { oldTopicID } );

            if( result == 0 )
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    } );

    return result;
}
```

in super class:

```
protected synchronized < T > T write( DatabaseWriteRequest<T> writeRequest )
{
    if( writeRequest == null )
        return null;

    T result = null;

    SQLiteDatabase database = DatabaseHolder.getDatabase();
    if( database != null )
        result = writeRequest.requestImplementation( database );

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Are you using transactions explicitly? The Service and the other components sharing the same connection?

Comment: Show the code you used to add the data to the database.

Comment: I am not using transaction, actually I don't know how. although I am setting database.enableWriteAheadLogging();

Comment: I figured out after spending the whole day that the db is not actually empty but my queries are not returning any value. and that's because I am updating the db with null values!!!!!